# How can I make sure a Websocket does not open before attaching an onopen handler?

Tags: javascript, websocket

There's a part of the [Websockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) I do not understand.

The `onOpen` event handler is usually used to start sending messages to the server, since we can't do that before the socket is opened and ready.

According to any code examples I can find ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Example)), this is the common way to register an `onOpen` eventhandler on a Websocket:

```
1: const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
2: 
3: socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
4:     socket.send('Hello Server!');
5: });
```

But the WebSocket contstructor call (line 1) creates the websocket [*and attempts to open a connection to the server*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications), while the event handler is attached later (line 3).

So: In a case where the connection is established (very) quickly, is it not possible that `socket` *is already open* when we reach line 3?
In which case we will miss the `open` event, since we did not have an event handler registered for it when it happened.

How are we guaranteed to receive the `open` event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript implementation in browsers is asynchronous and single threaded. Of course, it can use multiple worker threads inside (for example, for input/output operations or timers), but your application code is executing on one thread with event loop.

When you connect to the server through WebSocket:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
```

JavaScript thread starts asynchronous operation for connecting socket and immediately continues to run next code. It can receive events from asynchronous operations only when it returns to the event loop. That means, that your `onOpen` listener will be always fired, no matter how quickly connection will be established.

I also recommend you to check this question:

[How does Asynchronous programming work in a single threaded programming model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982489/how-does-asynchronous-programming-work-in-a-single-threaded-programming-model)

You'll find there a little bit better and extended explanations. Note, that [V8 JavaScript engine](https://developers.google.com/v8/) is used by Node.js and Chromium.

Comment: So even if I add a really time consuming operation on line 6 in the script above, there's no chance that my event handler will be missed?

Comment: Right. Also, your web page can lag during that long running operations, because main thread event loop will be blocked and you'll not receive any events.

Comment: Interesting, and makes sense. Thanks!